# How to bulk transfer Salesforce reports from one .org to another clean .org?

Tags: xml, database, salesforce, data-migration

My task is to upload all of the reports of an old .org to a completely new .org

I found that it is possible to retrieve reports via .xml-files from an old .org and upload it to a new org **via workbench**. Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
   <members>FOLDERA/REPORTA</members>
   <members>FOLDERB/REPORTB</members>
   <name>Report</name>
</types>
<version>43.0</version>
```

I've tested this way and it does work fine

BUT

the old .org contains thousands of reports and it would be quite tiresome to go through each folder at a time, customizing the .xml files each time.

Calling * just retrieved an empty folder called "unpacked" cotaining the .xml file called "packaged" but unfortunately nothing more.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package
xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
<version>43.0</version>
```

Is there a way to mass download, transfer and upload all the reports and files at once, so that I have the exact same structure in the new and yet "clean" .org?

I'd appreciate any feedback!

Thank you already in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To do it completely automated is bit messy. You'd need to learn the folder names, then there's Metadata API call to [`listMetadata`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_listmetadata.htm) in which you give folder name (report, dashboard, email template...) and it tells you what's inside. There's way to automate it (old development tool called Force.com IDE was able to, if you have a developer using VSCode there's [decent plugin for building that package.xml](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator)...) Might be too much investment in tooling if you just need an one-off.

See if this query gives you promising results

```
SELECT FolderName, DeveloperName
FROM Report
ORDER BY FolderName, DeveloperName
```

Throw results into Excel, some formulas, mass search-replace and you should be able to create `<member>...</member>` rows for your package?